# How do I get Google (or others) to pay me for putting ads on my site?

Tags: ads, google-adsense, google-adwords

Let's say that I have a super popular blog and I want to start making some ad revenue from the people that come there. I'm looking for a basic "how-to" and possibly some links to get me started.

How do I set it up so that ads are automatically placed on my page and so that when someone clicks them I am automatically paid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest is using one of your tags - google adsense.  Apply and paste their javascript code into your site.  You get paid for every click of an ad.

You can also sell your adspace on a market like buysellads.com, assuming you have enough traffic and a topic that people would like to advertise on.  There advertisers will put their ads on your site.  You simply get paid for them putting it there or by impressions.